# Can selected columns change the number of rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I have a simple query with a couple of joins but when I add columns in to my selection from the same set of joins, number of rows change by just adding or removing columns in selection without changing any joins.

Comment: Hi, please show us the query or the best example of it ?

Comment: please make sure you elaborate your question by adding examples & your output

Comment: @MatBailie I really appreciate you and other guys who came here to help me out. I was just to get ideas as I was facing the issues. Question & Description are enough to tell the case instead of giving example code. And yes I got the answer. But I am still thankful to you as you came for my help <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes they can. Your query or as you call it "simple query" can have, for example, keyword distinct and adding a column to a select like that will change the number of total rows in your result.

```
select distinct t1.id, t2.id
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

VS

```
select distinct t1.id, t2.id, t2.job
from t1
left join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ecece2eb90b1cb134735322e969ce56e)

Comment: That was the thing I was looking for. Thank You.

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to be of help.